# Error: _mm_clmulepi64_si128 was not declared in this scope

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to use the carry-less multiplication instruction found on the new intel/amd processor `_mm_clmulepi64_si128 ()`

I have included the header file and I am compiling with the `-maes -msse4` options... but i still get an error saying:

error: _mm_clmulepi64_si128 was not declared in this scope

```
#include < immintrin.h >
#include < wmmintrin.h >

int main()

{

    __m128i a;
    __m128i b;

    a.m128i_i64[1] = 2;
    a.m128i_i64[0] = -1284;
    b.m128i_i64[1] = 25;
    b.m128i_i64[0] = 65535;

    const int product1 = 0x11;
    const int product2 = 0x00;
    const int product3 = 0xF2;

    int expect1 = int ( a.m128i_i64[1] * b.m128i_i64[1] );
    int expect2 = int ( a.m128i_i64[0] * b.m128i_i64[0] );
    int expect3 = int ( a.m128i_i64[0] * b.m128i_i64[1] );

    __m128i result1 = _mm_clmulepi64_si128( a, b, product1 );
    __m128i result2 = _mm_clmulepi64_si128( a, b, product2 );
    __m128i result3 = _mm_clmulepi64_si128( a, b, product3 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which operating system, which version of which compiler? Did you look in `immintrin.h` if the function is declared there? Are you sure that the version of the compiler and header files you use supports this instruction? (Look in the documentation of your compiler).

Comment: Isn't this more `C` than `C++`? Sorry for being a pedant...

Comment: OS is Ubuntu.. compiler is g++ 4.6.1.. and Dennis, you are right.. it is C.. i pasted the wrong one... its the C version found in the manual... i was compiling it to see if there was something wrong with my version... but i get the same error with both files... there is also another header file that for some reason isn't showing int he first post... (wmmintrin.h).

Comment: The C++ compiler gives the error “blammy was not declared in this scope”, when it can not resolve the name "blammy".  Make sure you are not missing another include file.

Comment: Can you try removing the whitespaces from the `#include <immintrin.h>`s ? Are they part of the original code, or only a bad copy-paste?

Comment: the white spaces are not in the source code... and the include files are all those that were required in the manual... so i don't think it has anything to do with a missing include...

Answer (score 4):

You need to compile with `-mpclmul` and `-msse4.1` to use `_mm_clmulepi64_si128()`. You also need to include the proper header file. Under Clang and GCC, you should include `<x86intrin.h>`. Intel, VC++ and other compilers need `<wmmintrin.h>`.

***If*** you processor is modern and supports the instruction, then `-march=native` should get all the features of the processor, including SSE4_1, SSE4_2, PCLMUL, AVX, AVX2, BMI, BMI2, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
```

instead of

```
#include <immintrin.h>
```

and set gcc flag -msse2 -msse4.1 -mpclmul.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that name mangeling is in your way. Make sure that you use a C Compiler instead if a C++ compiler, i.e. call gcc source.c -options.... instead of g++

And you still need a CPU which supports this extenstion.